# iframe next page button for src (non array, actual src change)

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe

I want to be able to change the source of an iframe but not the ways that I have found.
I want the iframe to start as http://www.example.com/1 then with the click of a Next button have the source change to http://www.example.com/2  but only the number needs to change.
So far I've found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
clicks += 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Which is great for keeping track of clicks on a page but I want to append the iframe src with the next number and have it load, sequentially.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you share a fiddle of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and works:

```
 <script>
 var c=1;
 var url="http://www.google.com/";
 function f(){
 document.getElementById("clicks").src = url+c;
 c++;
 }
 </script>

 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/1" id="clicks" >

 </iframe>

 <input type=button onclick="f()">
```